# Multiple Approval Step For Different Approval Step Criteria and Approvers

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

The scenario is we have one threshold value if that threshold value is less than or equal to 10 and the vertical is equal to "A" then it should approve by the chief(user P) only and if the threshold value is greater than 10 and vertical equals "A" then it should first approve by the chief(user P) then it goes to the approval of the CEO(user Q) up to this the approval process working fine but now I need setup same for the vertical B and for the different approvers (users R and S). Can I set up this in a single approval process. I have tried it in a single approval process but it is not working. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using two separate approval processes with separate entry criteria; i.e. one for vertical "A" and one for vertical "B" (you may need to consider a catch-all if not "A" or "B"?).  The logic in the approval processes themselves would be largely similar (other than the approvers).

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for the reply.